# Is there a way to filter matched elements that didn't fire event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a lot of elements with a `.photo` class on my page.

I select them this way:

```
 $('#photos-container .photo').hover ...
```

Is there a way to filter out the elements that didn't fire the hover event?

Comment: Do you mean "elements that are not currently hovered"? I don't understand how you can do something with elements when an event *isn't* fired...

Comment: So what do you want to do with them?

Comment: I think you should explain what you're trying to accomplish. It could be that you could do it with CSS. Or it may be that you haven't given `hover` a second callback function and you're trying to undo the hover.

Comment: I mean, it's not that complicated. When one element is hovered, I want to act on the elements that aren't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
$('#photos-container .photo').hover(function(e) {
  var elementsThatDidntFire = $('#photos-container .photo').not(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.not` filtering:

```
$('#photos-container .photo').hover(function() {
    $('#photos-container .photo').not(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $('#photos-container .photo').not(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/T6xGj/5/

Answer (score 2):

Similar to DaDaDom's answer, but it caches the elements so you don't reselect on every event.

```
var photos = $('#photos-container .photo').hover(function(e) {
  var elementsThatDidntFire = photos.not(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#photos-container .photo').hover(function(e) {
    var elementsThatDidntFire = $('#photos-container .photo').filter(function() {
        return this !== e.target;
    });
}, function() {

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aUmNK/3/